# tesseract 5.0 bazaar + user-words config doesn't work

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I tried to force tesseract to use only my words list when perform OCR.
First, i copy bazaar file to `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata/configs/`. This is my bazaar file:

```
load_system_dawg F
load_freq_dawg F
user_words_suffix user-words
```

Then, i created `eng.user-words` in `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata`. This is my user-words file:

```
Items
VAT
included
CASH
```

then i perform ocr for this image by command: `tesseract -l eng --oem 2 test_small.jpg stdout bazaar`.

[image: test_img]

this is my result:

```
2 Item(s) (VAT includsd) 36,000
casH 40,000
CHANGE 4. 000
```

As you can see, `includsd` is not in my user-words file, and it should be 'included'. Besides, i got same result even without using `bazaaz` config in command. It looks like that my `bazaar` and `eng.user-words` config doesn't have any effect in OCR output. So how can use `bazaar` and `user-words` config, in order to get desired result ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My interpretation of the documentation is the same as yours, in that you should be able to provide a 'whitelist' of words.

Comment: at that time, I didn't found any solution and gave up. But it has been 2 years, so you should check documentation. It can support now @comfytoday

Comment: This document is somewhat relevant https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample-user_patterns.html But in terms of only using the user words supplied I can't anything like that. I don't think it's possible without compiling your own dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

`user_words_suffix` does not seem to work for `--oem 2`.
A workaround is to use `user_words_file` which contains the path to your user-words file.

Comment: can you post for me an example command ? i can not find your option from tesseract manual: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc

Comment: i add this option to my bazaar file, but it doesn't work: `user_words_file /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata/eng.user-words`

Comment: @voxter what do you mean with "it does't work" do you get any Error message? A user-words file is not a word whitelist, tesseract is not only using words from the user-words file.

Comment: "it doesn't work" means that i got same result before using this option

Comment: do we have any other idea ?

Comment: @voxter Like I mentioned in my comment above, the user-words file is only a hint for tesseract it does not mean that only word from this list are recognized. I think the only thing you could do is providing a better image.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do was up-sampling the image.

If you up-sample two - times

[image]

Now read:

```
2 Item(s) (VAT included) 36,000
CASH 40,000
CHANGE 4,000
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("4nGXo.jpg")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Up-sample
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(gry))

# Display
cv2.imshow("", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your approach is about resizing image in order to get better result. But i want to configure tesseract in order to use only words in my dictionary, not about getting better result